# Computing percentage change using arrange, groupby and indexing

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a reprex:

```
library(crypto2)
library(dplyr)

coins = crypto_list(only_active = TRUE)

coins = coins[(coins$symbol %in% c("BTC","ETH")),]

thirteen.months.data = crypto_history(coins, start_date=Sys.Date() - (13 * 30))

mydf <- thirteen.months.data[substr(thirteen.months.data$timestamp,1,10) %in% as.character((Sys.Date()-c(1,31,366))),] %>% select(timestamp,name,close,market_cap) %>% arrange(name,timestamp) %>% as.data.frame

# Present

df1  <- mydf %>% group_by(name) %>% slice(3) %>% select(-1)

# M-o-M growth

df2  <- mydf %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(m.o.m  = (close[3]-close[2])/close[2]*100)

# Y-o-Y growth

df3 <- mydf %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(y.o.y = (close[3]-close[1])/close[1]*100)
```

I have 2 queries regarding the above program.

1. Will the group_by which is done ***after*** the arrange mess up the ordering which has been done using arrange?
2. Will the m.o.m ( month on month ) / y.o.y ( year on year ) work as expected? In other words if I do close[2] ***after*** group by, will it use the second element in ***each*** group? Is this way of indexing allowed?

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. But `nth()` could be useful here.

Comment: You mean a ***yes*** for second query don't you?

Comment: No, `close[2]` won't return the second element in each group (afaik). But you could use `nth(close, 2)` to get this element. There are similiar verbs (`first`, `last`) that also work on grouped data.

Comment: @MartinGal, `mtcars %>% mutate(disp2a = disp[2]) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(disp2b = disp[2]) %>% ungroup()` demonstrates that `disp2a` is the second value of `cyl`, repeated across all rows, and `disp2b` is the second value of `cyl` _per `cyl`_. Within a `group_by` execution, `[` sees a vector which consists of the subset of the original vector (by its grouping variable); it works just fine.

Comment: The risk of using `[`-indexing is if the group has insufficient rows, appears to not be a concern in this example; if a vector is too short, then `[` just returns `NA`. The `nth(.)` function does the same thing; but it adds the value of ordering by another vector (though this can be done in base with some nested code).

Comment: @r2evans Oh, thanks you for this insight. I really wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, issuing a `group_by` has absolutely no effect on the order of the data. By demonstrating how grouping is done, realize that its group-indexing is *based* on the order of the frame.

   ```r
   X <- data.frame(id=1:3, grp=c(4,6,4))
   group_by(X, grp) %>%
     attr("groups") %>%
     str()
   # tibble [2 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
   #  $ grp  : num [1:2] 4 6
   #  $ .rows: list<int> [1:2] 
   #   ..$ : int [1:2] 1 3
   #   ..$ : int 2
   #   ..@ ptype: int(0) 
   #  - attr(*, ".drop")= logi TRUE
   ```

   The `groups` *attribute* of the grouped frame is not normally shown raw, though its content informs the printing of it, `# Groups:   grp [2]`. In this example, the first element of `.rows` is `c(1, 3)`, indicating that the first group consists of rows 1 and 3.

   From this, one can understand that the grouping is handled by an internal structure that keeps track of rows in whatever order they may have been. (With some more effort, one can see that if you reorder the rows, the `groups`/`.rows` attribute adjusts.)
2. Yes, `[`-indexing works as expected. Using another example,

   ```r
   mtcars %>%
     mutate(disp2a = disp[2]) %>%
     group_by(cyl) %>%
     mutate(disp2b = disp[2]) %>%
     ungroup()
   # # A tibble: 32 × 13
   #      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb disp2a disp2b
   #    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
   #  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4    160   160 
   #  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4    160   160 
   #  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1    160   147.
   #  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1    160   160 
   #  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2    160   360 
   #  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1    160   160 
   #  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4    160   360 
   #  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2    160   147.
   #  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2    160   147.
   # 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4    160   160 
   # # … with 22 more rows
   # # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
   ```

   Note that `disp2a` (the second element of `disp` with no grouping) is `160` for all rows, and `disp2b` (the second element of `disp` within each group) shows variability between groups (invariability within each group).

As @MartinGal suggested, though, the `nth` helper-function can be useful here as well:

```r
mtcars %>%
  mutate(disp2a = nth(disp, 2)) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(disp2b = nth(disp, 2)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Its arguments effectively give the same functionality we get with `[`: `n=` (the index(ices); `order_by=mpg` can be mimicked with `disp[order(mpg)][2]` (with `n=2`); and `default=` allows one to change what happens when indexed outside of range (R's default behavior is to return `NA`):

```r
(1:3)[4]
# [1] NA
nth(1:3, 4)
# [1] NA
nth(1:3, 4, default = Inf)
# [1] Inf
```